# Rspec 3 upgrade issues with view.stub (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm upgrading my tests to Rspec3 (what a bother), removing all my 'shoulds', but I can't work out how to upgrade 'view.stub' in my view tests.

I am using devise

example:

```
view.stub(:current_user) { nil }

render

expect(rendered).to .... etc
```

This gives me a deprecation warning:

> Using `stub` from rspec-mocks' old `:should` syntax without explicitly enabling the syntax is deprecated. Use the new `:expect` syntax or explicitly enable `:should` instead. Called from ....

I can't work out how to upgrade to the new 'improved' syntax.
Thanks

Comment: By the way, there's [a tool](https://github.com/yujinakayama/transpec) to convert automatically to RSpec 3 syntax.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
allow(view).to receive_messages(current_user: nil)
```

[Notable Changes in RSpec 3](http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2014/05/notable-changes-in-rspec-3)

Comment: Indeed, the deprecation message is completely confusing. Go to section [RSpec Mocks](http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2014/05/notable-changes-in-rspec-3#rspecmocks) in Notable Changes in RSpec 3.

Comment: Hi, what is the equivalent of this old code. ENV.stub(:[])
   ENV.stub(:[]).with(name).and_return(value)

Comment: `allow(ENV).to receive(:[]).with(name).and_return(value)`

Answer (score 4):

You can also use:

```
allow(view).to receive(:current_user).and_return(nil)
```

I personally find it more readable. See the [docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-mocks/RSpec/Mocks/ExampleMethods#receive_messages-instance_method) for extra info